# If condición sintaxis

Tags: c++

`if (x==1 ||x==0 && y==2 || y==0 && z==3 || z==0)`
Me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de hacer que el operador || solo afecte a la variable que tiene delante como si hubiera un paréntesis. **(x=1 or x=0) and (y=2 or y=0) and (z=3 or z=0)**

Comment: Eso se logra usando paréntesis de forma adecuada. De otra forma, el compilador va a resolver los operadores de acuerdo a la precedencia predefinida

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar los mismos paréntesis para separar las expresiones,
sería algo así.

```
    if ( (x==1 || x==0) && (y==2 || y==0) && (z==3 || z==0)  )
    {


    }
```

Donde se evaluaran las expresiones (x==1 || x==0), (y==2 || y==0) y (z==3 || z==0) y luego dichos resultados se evaluaran con el and.

Espero que te haya servido.

Saludos.